# com. prefix meaning on Android apps

Tags: android, process, prefix

What does mean the **com.** prefix in some Android processes?

E.g.: com.whatsapp, com.google.android.gapps, com.android.mms, com.antivirus, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

com. prefix indicates the package name of android application(Since android based on JAVA: class-package concept).

Naming convention is adopted to avoid the name collision

Companies use their reversed Internet domain name to begin their package names—for example, com.whatsapp.mypackage for a package named mypackage created by a programmer at whatsapp.com

Name collisions that occur within a single company need to be handled by convention within that company, perhaps by including the region or the project name after the company name (for example, com.android.mms, com.antivirus).

Answer (score 1):

It is the standard business top-level domain (TLD) for domain names on the Internet.

Convention in Java package names is to reverse your domain name to give you a namespace that is unlikely to collide with other Java classes. Android also uses this convention for the "application ID", and once again the reverse-domain-name approach is to prevent accidental collisions.